# Quarkus - DynamoDB + HTTP lambda slow first response

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, quarkus

I have created a test project where I have combined two guides: [Quarkus-DynamoDB](https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-dynamodb) and [Quarkus-HTTP lambda](https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda-http). The end goal of this was to have an example project where a lambda communicates with DynamoDB, and this is all compiled natively (using GraalVM).

This has worked relatively well. I managed to deploy the project to AWS lambda using the tools from the second guide, and the responses I get when calling the endpoints are as expected.

However, I have some questions about the performance, particularly after a startup.

When hitting the simple "hello" endpoint from the first guide, the times look like this:

```
2021-05-09T20:41:06.986+02:00   START RequestId: ccc69797-3e58-47b1-a475-f2b0cc93cd7d Version: $LATEST

2021-05-09T20:41:06.986+02:00   __ ____ __ _____ ___ __ ____ ______

2021-05-09T20:41:06.986+02:00   --/ __ \/ / / / _ | / _ \/ //_/ / / / __/

2021-05-09T20:41:06.986+02:00   -/ /_/ / /_/ / __ |/ , _/ ,< / /_/ /\ \

2021-05-09T20:41:06.986+02:00   --\___\_\____/_/ |_/_/|_/_/|_|\____/___/

2021-05-09T20:41:06.986+02:00   2021-05-09 18:41:06,980 INFO [io.quarkus] (main) quarkus-amazon-lambda-http-archetype 1.0-SNAPSHOT native (powered by Quarkus 1.13.3.Final) started in 0.239s.

2021-05-09T20:41:06.986+02:00   2021-05-09 18:41:06,985 INFO [io.quarkus] (main) Profile prod activated.

2021-05-09T20:41:06.986+02:00   2021-05-09 18:41:06,985 INFO [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [amazon-dynamodb, amazon-lambda, cdi, mutiny, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, resteasy-mutiny, smallrye-context-propagation]

2021-05-09T20:41:07.225+02:00   END RequestId: ccc69797-3e58-47b1-a475-f2b0cc93cd7d

2021-05-09T20:41:07.225+02:00   REPORT RequestId: ccc69797-3e58-47b1-a475-f2b0cc93cd7d Duration: 237.21 ms Billed Duration: 623 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 92 MB Init Duration: 385.04 ms
```

We can see from this that it takes about 0.25 seconds to receive a response after startup (Which is to be expected I think, I have literally no experience with this). However, when hitting the endpoint "fruits", which returns a list of fruits (duh), the time is looking a little different:

```
2021-05-09T20:23:00.521+02:00   START RequestId: 1ee2002c-15ad-491e-b24a-591b8d371bae Version: $LATEST

2021-05-09T20:23:00.521+02:00   __ ____ __ _____ ___ __ ____ ______

2021-05-09T20:23:00.521+02:00   --/ __ \/ / / / _ | / _ \/ //_/ / / / __/

2021-05-09T20:23:00.521+02:00   -/ /_/ / /_/ / __ |/ , _/ ,< / /_/ /\ \

2021-05-09T20:23:00.521+02:00   --\___\_\____/_/ |_/_/|_/_/|_|\____/___/

2021-05-09T20:23:00.521+02:00   2021-05-09 18:23:00,516 INFO [io.quarkus] (main) quarkus-amazon-lambda-http-archetype 1.0-SNAPSHOT native (powered by Quarkus 1.13.3.Final) started in 0.249s.

2021-05-09T20:23:00.522+02:00   2021-05-09 18:23:00,521 INFO [io.quarkus] (main) Profile prod activated.

2021-05-09T20:23:00.522+02:00   2021-05-09 18:23:00,521 INFO [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [amazon-dynamodb, amazon-lambda, cdi, mutiny, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, resteasy-mutiny, smallrye-context-propagation]

2021-05-09T20:23:01.657+02:00   END RequestId: 1ee2002c-15ad-491e-b24a-591b8d371bae

2021-05-09T20:23:01.657+02:00   REPORT RequestId: 1ee2002c-15ad-491e-b24a-591b8d371bae Duration: 1133.83 ms Billed Duration: 1539 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 103 MB Init Duration: 404.57 ms

2021-05-09T20:23:30.341+02:00   START RequestId: a546afa3-78a2-4219-8cef-075694c320ac Version: $LATEST

2021-05-09T20:23:30.456+02:00   END RequestId: a546afa3-78a2-4219-8cef-075694c320ac

2021-05-09T20:23:30.456+02:00   REPORT RequestId: a546afa3-78a2-4219-8cef-075694c320ac Duration: 111.38 ms Billed Duration: 112 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 105 MB

2021-05-09T20:24:53.644+02:00   START RequestId: 65104eb8-1e53-453a-bd67-ef25d3a919af Version: $LATEST

2021-05-09T20:24:53.815+02:00   END RequestId: 65104eb8-1e53-453a-bd67-ef25d3a919af

2021-05-09T20:24:53.815+02:00   REPORT RequestId: 65104eb8-1e53-453a-bd67-ef25d3a919af Duration: 168.10 ms Billed Duration: 169 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 107 MB
```

We can see that the first request takes over a second (and I've observed it taking longer) before getting a response. The requests after hit the same endpoint, but are quite quick (a lot faster, even if you were to add the startup time on top of it).

So the timing here is what I am wondering about. Why does it take so much longer to get a response from the first request from DynamoDB, and is there any way I can improve this?

Comment: Hi Robert! How you connected you AWS Lambda Quarkus app with DynamoDB? Did you use env variables to provide AWS Access Keys or you created a new policy for connection purposes? I'm looking a right track do this..

Comment: @piotrowicki When running it locally, yes, you need environment variables if you want to call the dynamodb on AWS. However, when it runs on lambda, you specify a role with permissions for the lambda. For that role you want to add dynamodb permissions.

I think for this I set the region in the application.properties file for both locally and on the lambda, as I was just testing things out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first call to a "new" Lambda instance takes longer because it has to be *initialised*. This is also referred to as [cold start](https://mikhail.io/serverless/coldstarts/aws/).

Check the following two lines of your second output example:

```
Duration: 1133.83 ms Billed Duration: 1539 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 103 MB Init Duration: 404.57 ms
```

and

```
Duration: 111.38 ms Billed Duration: 112 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 105 MB
```

At the end of the first line is this: `Init Duration: 404.57 ms`. The second does not have this, because it did not need to be initialised.

The point is: when a new Lambda instance is started it needs to be initialised and that takes time. You can not do anything about this, except for trying to make initialisation as fast as possible if latency is your highest priority. You could try to reduce the package size (the smaller the better), you should avoid any unnecessary work in your initialisation code and maybe it helps to increase your Lambdas memory.

On the other hand, there are a lot of things that you absolutely should do in the initialisation phase of your Lambda, like creating service clients, reading configuration from SSM or S3 or DynamoDB, etc. But all of these are prolonging the initialisation of your Lambda. The upside is that all the following requests are faster because they do not have to do that.

If you can not improve initialisation any further, but you are still not happy with the first call latency, then as far as I can tell you have two options:

1. Choose another runtime that has faster "cold start" times.
2. [Use provisioned concurrency](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-provisioned-concurrency-for-lambda-functions/).

Be aware, that provisioned concurrency does cost extra.

Comment: Provisioned concurrency is in most cases a bad design IMO. The whole point of Lambda is the scalability, for me that includes scaling to 0.

Comment: @appel500 No argument there. I wouldn't want to use it either unless I have exhausted all other options.